# SQL query to count the number of rows in different columns with group by clauses

Tags: mysql, sql

In my Mysql database, I have 2 columns that store the start and end date of the process, respectively. I need to write a query that allows me to count the number of rows for each month in each column, and presents the count separately.

Table example:

```
+----+------------+----------------+
| id | startData  |     endData    |
+----+-------------+----------------+
|  1 | 02/03/2020 |    02/03/2020  | 
|  2 | 02/04/2020 |    02/04/2020  |
|  3 | 02/04/2020 |    02/05/2020  |
|  4 | 02/04/2020 |    02/05/2020  |
|  5 | 02/05/2020 |    02/06/2020  |
|  6 | 02/05/2020 |    02/06/2020  |
|  7 | 02/06/2020 |    02/07/2020  |
+----+-------------+----------------+
```

I want as a result:

```
+-------+--------------------+-------------------+
| month |  count_month_start |  count_month_end  |
+-------+--------------------+-------------------+
|  03   |         01         |          01       |
|  04   |         03         |          01       |
|  05   |         02         |          02       |
|  06   |         01         |          02       |
|  07   |         00         |          01       |
+-------+--------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: please give us query to populate data, you can use http://sqlfiddle.com/ for that

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Your data does not match default MySQL datetime data format. Edit your sample.

Comment: Have you even tried anything????  If not, get to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your start date and end date columns are of datatype date, you can do -

```
Select ifnull(Tb1.mn,Tb2.mn) As mn, ifnull(count_mn_start,0) As count_mn_start, ifnull(count_mn_end,0) As count_mn_end
 from
 (Select Month(StartDate) as mn, count(id) as count_mn_start
  from
  my_table
 Group by Month(StartDate))Tb1
 left Join (Select Month(EndDate) as mn, count(id) as count_mn_end
  from my_table
  Group by Month(EndDate)) Tb2
  on Tb1.mn = Tb2.mn
UNION
 Select ifnull(Tb1.mn,Tb2.mn) As mn, ifnull(count_mn_start,0) As count_mn_start, ifnull(count_mn_end,0) As count_mn_end
 from
 (Select Month(StartDate) as mn, count(id) as count_mn_start
  from
  my_table
 Group by Month(StartDate))Tb1
 Right Join (Select Month(EndDate) as mn, count(id) as count_mn_end
  from my_table
  Group by Month(EndDate)) Tb2
  on Tb1.mn = Tb2.mn;
```

DB fiddle - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=84ecddb9f5ed431ddff6a9eaab87e5df

PS : If your dates only have one year (2020 as your example) this would work, however ideally if you have different years in the data, consider having the year in the output as well and in that case use the same syntax ie Year(datefield) and add it in the select and group by in the sub-queries (same way as month in the above query).

Comment: Your answer does not match what was requested. Using the Join clause, only results are combined in which both counts show results (count_mn_star, count_mn_end). If for one month, one of the counts is equal to zero, the result does not appear in the final table. For example: If I have 3 processes started in June and this month no process has been completed, the line [June :( 3 | 0)] will not appear.                                                                                                                                                      Please correct the code if you know the solution.

Comment: Thanks for flagging! I have edited the query and have also provided a db fiddle link in the response. The approach became complicated since MySQL doesn't allow full outer join so to overcome that I had to do a union of the left and right outer sets,

Answer (score 0):

A pretty simple way is to expand the time periods into days using a recursive CTE.  Then just aggregate:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select id, startdate as dte, enddate
      from t
      union all
      select id, dte + interval 1 day, enddate
      from cte
      where dte < enddate
     )
select year(dte), month(dte),
       sum( day(dte) = 1 ) as cnt_start,
       sum( day(dte) = day(last_day(dte)) ) as cnt_end
from cte
group by year(dte), month(dte) ;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bd0c676e587e9d0f13c0b8a822a46a4a) is a db<>fiddle.